# Размещение элементов Windows Form или WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Есть файл с json и необходимо каждый элемент разместить в форме, не создавая их вручную.
Как посредством кода разместить их на форме?

Comment: И файл и форма существуют только в вашем воображении. Каким образом можно ответить на ваш вопрос, если вы ничего толком не спросили?

Answer (score 3):

Вот ссылка https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/319266/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-windows-forms-at-run-time-by-u
Я разберу конкретный случай с добавлением button1 
добавим переменную btnAdd

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button btnAdd = new Button();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Потом в Form1_Load добавляем свойства к btn

```
this.btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    this.btnAdd.Text = "Добавить";
    this.btnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(412, 400);
    this.btnAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 40);
```

Добавляем элемент в форму в Form1_Load

```
this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
```